# Infinity in ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am not an ActionScript expert, but I unfortunately have to fix some broken flash files.

I fixed most problems except one:

```
class IndexNode extends Object
{
    var x1:Number = 1.#INF;
    var y2:Number = -1.#INF;
    var y1:Number = 1.#INF;
    var x2:Number = -1.#INF;

    function IndexNode()
    {
        x1 = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        x2 = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        y1 = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        y2 = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        return;
    }
}
```

This yields "invalid syntax" and "comma expected before #INF" errors on the variable declarations. What is this supposed to do, and why doesn't it works? Most search engines ignore the hash sign, so I couldn't google it :-(

Comment: was this decompiled?  "extends Object" looks decompiled and "1.#INF" isn't ActionScript code.  also, exactly like extending Object, the return at the end of the IndexNote() function is not necessary.  i think your decompiler isn't very accurate.

Comment: Yes, this was decompiled. Please post this as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply remove the first set of variable initializations.  They're irrelevant since the variables are instance variables (that is, not static).  As a result, the initializations in the constructor will overwrite those values anyway.

I suspect that the first set of initializations was just a duplicate way of doing the same thing, but regardless, it's not needed.

Comment: All occurrences of 1.#INF and -1.#INF (string form) should probably be replaced with Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY and Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY (proper actionscript form) unless they're useless like these are.